# Given the set $D$ compute its triple integral in two different orders

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given the set $D = \{(x, y, z) \in R^3 : 0<z<y<2 ; 0<x<2y + z\}$ compute the integral in the orders $dx\,dy\,dz$ and $dz\,dy\,dx$.
My problem is that I cant find the upper and lower bounds for $z$ in the first case and for $x$ in the second case.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to find the volume $\iiint_D\,\mathrm{d}V$, or is there more to the problem?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking to do, but in the given orders. I'm sorry if I wasn't explicit enough, english isn't my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In either order, the limits of the last variable ($z$ and $x$, respectively) can be determined by figuring out the vertices of the pentahedron bounded by $D$.

You can do this is by solving case-by-case the following system (which is just a list of all the bounding planes given in the definition of $D$):
$$\begin{cases}z=0\\z=y\\y=2\\2y+z=x\\x=0\end{cases}$$
To find the possible locations of each vertex, you can construct a table like this:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
x&y&z&\text{vertex}\\
\hline
0&2&0&(0,2,0)\\
0&2&y&(0,2,2)\\
0&z&0&(0,0,0)\\
0&z&y&\text{no unique solution}\\
2y+z&2&0&(4,2,0)\\
2y+z&2&y&(6,2,2)\\
2y+z&z&0&(0,0,0)\\
2y+z&z&y&\text{no unique solution}
\end{array}$$
This means that in the first order of integration, you would have $0<z<2$, and in the second, you would use $0<x<6$ (well, not exactly; see my edit).

**Added**:

Here's a graphic showing the bounding planes (somewhat transparent) surrounding the pentahedron (blue). (Rendered in Mathematica; I picked out two viewing angles that seemed sufficient to me to be able to make out the region well enough.)

[image]

For the first order, $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z$, we are essentially already given a convenient set of bounds for each variable.

$$D=D_{x,y,z}=\{(x,y,z):0<x<2y+z,\,z<y<2,\,0<z<2\}$$

and so the volume is given by

$$\iiint_{D_{x,y,z}}\mathrm{d}V=\int_0^2\int_z^2\int_0^{2y+z}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z$$

The second order involves a bit more work. Considering the $z$ direction first, it's clear that the lower bound of $D$ is the plane $z=0$ (light orange) in one segment of the solid, while in another the lower bound would be the plane $z=x-2y$ (light purple). Meanwhile, the upper bound is uniform in the shape of the plane $z=y$ (light blue).

One way to work around this is, as you say, split up the integration region. In particular, we can split up the "base" of the pentahedron along the intersection of the two different lower bounds in the $z$ direction:

$$(z=0)\land(x=2y+z)\implies x=2y$$

and again along the intersection of this new plane with the plane $y=2$, since $y$ doesn't vary uniformly in the smaller sub-region obtained by the first splitting plane.

Here's a graphic with the region and these two splitting planes:

[image]

So now we write

$$D=D_{z,y,x}=D_1\cup D_2\cup D_3$$

where

$$D_1=\left\{(x,y,z):0<x<4,\,\frac{x}{2}<y<2,\,0<z<y\right\}\\
D_2=\left\{(x,y,z):0<x<4,\,0<y<\frac{x}{2},\,x-2y<z<y\right\}\\
D_3=\left\{(x,y,z):4<x<6,\,\frac{4}{3}<y<2,\,x-2y<z<y\right\}$$

The volume is then given by

$$\begin{align*}
\iiint_{D_{z,y,x}}\mathrm{d}V&=\left\{\iiint_{D_1}+\iiint_{D_2}+\iiint_{D_3}\right\}\mathrm{d}V\\[1ex]
&=\left\{\int_0^4\int_{x/2}^2\int_0^y+\int_0^4\int_0^{x/2}\int_{x-2y}^y+\int_4^6\int_{4/3}^2\int_{x-2y}^y\right\}\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}$$

Unless I made a mistake somewhere, both setups should give the same result.

Comment: But how do I know that I won't have to split the volume throughout different integrals? For example, the set given by the inequalities $x/2 < y < x; 0 < z < x; x < 1$. To compute the volume of this set in the order of integration $dx\,dy\,dz$ you'd have to split the volume throughout 6 different triple integrals.

Comment: @Pedro sorry, I assumed your question was about determining the last variable's limits. If I have time later today I'll add more details to the remaining setup of each integral.

Comment: It's okay, I wasn't clear enough, the next time I have a question I'll be sure to explain myself better.

Comment: @Pedro I've added some more details to my answer

Comment: In that last triple integral isn't the lower bound of the y variable x/3?

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer because you did some explendid work, thank you so much for your answer, you have no idea for how long this problem's been upsetting me!